# UITabBar above the status on first setViewControllers call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The app that I am working on works on iOS 7 (iPhone). I have a custom navigation where I have a menu on a `UIViewController` containing some buttons and a `UINavigationController` that plays the role of the container for the content of the `UIViewControllers` presented from the menu. (something like the facebook sliding menu)

The thing is that I need a custom `UINavigationBar` so I can't use `initWithRootViewController` initializer to add the root `UIViewController` on the `UINavigationController` so I have to use `setViewControllers` method whenever a user presses a menu button.

The problem is that at first, when the menu controller loads I have to open one of the menu `UIViewControllers` in the right side of the screen and whenever I do that, the navigation bar will go on top of the status bar. If I load then another view controller, everything comes to normal and the navigation bar will be ok, also if I delay displaying the first view controller by 0.1 seconds, the navigation bar is displayed fine..

Is there a way to refresh the navigation controller after I set the root `UIViewController` so that the screen refreshes or something?

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CustomNavBar class] toolbarClass:nil];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[viewController] animated:NO];

[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

[self addChildViewController:self.navigationController];

[self.navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I hope I was clear on what I want :), if not, sorry and add a comment and I try to clarify asap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution.

It seems that I had to wait until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method was called in the main view controller and just after that add the navigation controller on it..

This way it seems that the navigation bar is well positioned.